# How can I autocomplete column names in dplyr?

Tags: r, autocomplete, dplyr

I know I can do `names(df)` to get the columns of a dataframe. But is there a more convenient way to rename using `dplyr` in Rstudio?

Earlier:

```
names(df)=c("anew","bnew","cnew")
```

Now?:

```
library(dplyr)
rename(df, aold = anew, bold = bnew, cold= cnew)
```

`dplyr` makes it more difficult as I have to know/type both the old and new column names.

I can see certain conversations around autocompletion of column names in `dplyr` toolchain. But I can't seem to make it work and I have the latest RStudio.

https://plus.google.com/+SharonMachlis/posts/FHknZcbAdLE

Comment: What exactly is the question?  Wouldn't you need to know the old names for purposes of renaming them?

Comment: In the first eg., I don't need to type in the old column names. In the second one, I need to spell it out...

Comment: You could also do, e.g. `rename_(iris, .dots = setNames(names(iris), letters[1:5]))` and not have to type the old names.

Comment: Thanks! The 1st example works fine as well. I just wondering if there is a way to do it in dplyr/Rstudio too where autocompletion works.

Comment: Actually I think I was wrong about that :)

Comment: @RichardScriven The `rename_` with `.dots` approach works, but you really only need `setNames(iris, letters[1:5])` by itself.

Comment: @maximusdooku `dplyr` autocompletion in RStudio seems to be dependent on it knowing what data.frame you're working with. Bare `rename(iris, a = Petal.Width)` won't autocomplete, but if you chain into `rename` (`iris %>% rename(a = Petal.Width)`) it will. The behavior may change with updates, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using `names(*) <- new_value`. dplyr isn't the be-all and end-all of data manipulation in R.

That said, if you want to include this in a dplyr pipeline, here's how to do it:

```
df %>% `names<-`(c("a_new", "b_new", "c_new"))
```

This works because (almost) everything in R is a function, and in particular assigning new names is really a call to the `names<-` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this (you don't need to use dplyr to transform names automatically).  Just replace the `modify_names` function with whatever transformation you want to apply to the names.

```
> modify_names <- function(any_string) {
+    return(paste0(any_string, "-new"))
+ }
>


> df <- data.frame(c(0, 1, 2), c(3, 4, 5))
> names(df) <- c("a", "b")
> df
  a b
1 0 3
2 1 4
3 2 5


> names(df) <- modify_names(names(df))
> df
  a-new b-new
1     0     3
2     1     4
3     2     5
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had the same question and found this RStudio article: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205273297-Code-Completion

Following the article, to autocomplete column names with dplyr in RStudio you have to use the magrittr’s %>% operator (pipelines):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% rename(aold = anew, bold = bnew, cold= cnew) #Select the variable (old) name after typing the initials (3) + tab
```

You can find the visual example in the article and manipulate the completation delay (to type less) and other completation options in: RStudio>Tools>Global options...>Code>Completation>Completation delay.